# How to find clicked element and/or correct event in react/typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Please can someone help, I am trying to find which element is clicked using

`document.addEventListener('click', (evt: MouseEvent) => console.log(evt.toElement));`

I have tried many different types but either get event type is wrong or `toElement` does not exist on event.

Comment: use event.target
you can view more properties of the event object by consoling it.

Comment: damn, don't know how i missed that, thank you.